put enter key to = button as default in c# win form
how to do it
key pressed , key down
calculator in windows form
need to when enter key press go to = button
and when enter key pressed numbers dont select and just = key select
.................................................................

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask].
